# MVC CultureInfo language-code needed for Hmong

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, asp.net-core-localization

I am working on a MVC project that will have its pages in English, Spanish, and Hmong using CultureInfo. I am unsure what language code I should use for the Hmong translations. I haven't found anything related to it other than other than hmn(ISO 639-2 Code). Should I use this or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find Hmong to be a few different culture codes.  Our plant workers use a dashboard we wrote and their version of spoken Hmong most closely resembled vi-VN .  So that is the culture code we use when our Hmong workers switch their displays to their translated language.