# .NET Multi-language support for unsupported ISO 639-2 cultures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual, cultureinfo, .net-4.8

I am currently developing an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC single-page application that is expected to support multiple languages. From various resources, I found that one way to accomplish this is through the use of `App_GlobalResources` and resource files for each supported language.

I added some navigation links to my page that update the thread's current culture info, which pulls those language resources into my application.

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName == language);

if (cultureInfo == null)
     cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

This appears to work fine for languages that have culture support. (IE: "eng" pulls back `en-us` and finds the `Content.en.resx` file, "spa" retrieves `Content.es.resx`, etc.) But I'm running into difficulty where the languages appear in the ISO639-2 list (Hmong, Karen) but don't have CultureInfo associated with them.

I've tried spinning off Cultures for these using `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`, but from my understanding, this will only work on my computer, and not on the web. I'm also not able to 'hack' an existing Culture -- ie, taking Vietnamese and replacing its `ThreeLetterISOLanguageName` and other properties -- because those properties are readonly.

Is there an explicit way to tell my code to reference a specific content file when CultureInfo is not available? Or am I going about this the entirely wrong way?

Comment: I think I don't understand your exact problem. Your `language` corresponds to a `ThreeLetterISOLanguageName` and you retrieve the `CultureInfo` for it. What's your problem with e.g. `Karen`? (There is a CultureInfo available)

Comment: @kapsiR There is? Might it be dependent on .NET Core or some other external reference? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET 4.8. When I did CultureInfo searches for "kar" and "hmn", I found 0 references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355589/mvc-cultureinfo-language-code-needed-for-hmong

Comment: Thanks, @smoore4. Saw that one, but was hoping there was a less "hacky" approach than forcing a different culture match onto the language. I'll probably go that direction if there are no other answers forthcoming.

Comment: @MadHenchbot Today I checked it again and saw that I was wrong. In .NET Framework 4.X the CultureInfos come from the OS. [Here is a list of supported languages with the associated OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c).
I think you have to use the closest available...